# React-leaflet v4 drawer shows two duplicated drawer components

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, drawer

[image]I'm using react-leaflet v4 and simple leaflet
currently as  you see in the picture I receive doubled drawer component
here example of my code:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const map = useMap();
  const drawnItems = new FeatureGroup();
  map.addLayer(drawnItems);

  const drawControl = new Control.Draw({
    position: "topright",
    draw: {
      rectangle: false,
      circle: false,
      circlemarker: false,
    },
    edit: {
      featureGroup: drawnItems,
    },
  });
  map.addControl(drawControl);
  return null;
}
export const MapWindow = () => {
  return ( 
      <MapContainer
        center={myPosition}
        zoom={16}
        style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
      >
        <MyComponent/>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          //  url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>
  );
};
```